# Whole word search in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I need to implement whole word search in Elastic, which should work like these examples:

query: "the test"

must match these strings:

`this is the test`

`the test is necessary`

`I didn't write the test because I was sick.`

`the test\non the newline`

`the test`

**but not** these:

`this is the testing server`

`this test is very good`

`I wrote my test with the cheatsheet`

---

I have tried to use [regexp filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-regexp-filter.html) but there are several problems because Elasticsearch regexp syntax is not Perl-compatible, and so I cannot easily recognize boundaries of words. This can be solved with character classes, but there is another problem, because syntax obviously does not support `\n` expression and so I cannot even recognize newlines. Also there is problem with beginnings / endings of strings because regular expression must match whole string..

How can be this done with Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not well-wandered in Elasticsearch, but i think you're looking for a [_phrase query_](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html). I cannot provide a full answer, hence the comment.

Comment: @Dencker: Phrase query does not work well for this purpose because it also matches non-whole words (`the test` will match also `the testing server`).

Comment: @Thomas: `the test[\s]` also does not work because as I said, Elasticsearch does not support these Perl-like expressions..

Comment: Please provide the `mapping` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

An expansion of Dencker's answer (phrase queries does seem to be what you want and regexp might be a bad choice give the information so far):

I created [two quick bash scripts](https://gist.github.com/eemp/8bb18d566a57295dab96) that will create sample documents using your examples and make two simple phrase searches.

Basically, for the standard script where no mapping is specified early on, the text fields get the `standard` analyzer which does not include a stemmer.  The script demonstrates that a `match_phrase` query for "the test" only returns the two expected documents and not the document with "the testing" phrase.

But what might be happening in your case as bittusarkar was getting at is that you may have a mapping that specifies an analyzer like `snowball` that involves a stemmer that is stemming "testing" down to "test" which will mean that "the test" match_phrase query will also return the "the testing" document as the snowball script demonstrates.

To summarize the scripts (replace snowball with any potential analyzer with stemmer and stop):

"this is the test" :

`standard` : "test" (in my version standard analyzer has a stop word filter)

`snowball` : "test"

"the test\non the newline" :

`standard` : "test", "non", "newline"

`snowball` : "test", "non", "newlin"

"this is the testing server" :

`standard` : "testing", "server"

`snowball` : "test", "server"

"the test" (your query) : "test" (for both analyzers)

Considering how the analyzers and how the content might be getting index might explain why phrase queries are not working for you and will help you figure out how to get what you expect.  You might also want to consider multi field type to store a piece of content analyzed in multiple ways depending on how you want to query it.